# How to use Saxon XPath 2.0 with Java?

Tags: java, xpath, saxon

I like to use regular expressions in xPath, so I installed Saxon9.6

1. My ${java.home} is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51.
2. I extracted saxonHE9-6-0-6J.zip in C:\Program
   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext
3. and add saxonhe9.jar to my classpath variable.
4. Then I created a jaxp.properties file under C:\Program
   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib and add the following lines:

   javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl
   javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory","net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl

But now I cant find the examples like it is described on [this](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.7/samples.html#xpath-example) page.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

*<sup>(while this is the accepted answer currently, there is an important piece of information in [Michael Kay's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32726464/111575), which I think is a better answer to this question, but I can't change the accepted-answer flag...)</sup>*

It is quite easy to setup a transformation in Java using Saxon, just refer to [the documentation here](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!using-xsl/embedding/s9api-transformation). Another [straightforward how-to can be found here](http://codingwithpassion.blogspot.nl/2011/03/saxon-xslt-java-example.html). Other examples are scattered all over the Net.

The [XPath API for Java is documented here at Saxonica](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!xpath-api).

Note, your link is referencing a version 7.7. You downloaded version 9.6. If you want to use samples from 7.7, you should probably download that version. They may still be somewhat accurate, but I'm not sure.

Comment: your second link is an example about xslt transforamtion. I want to use the xPath API.

Comment: @StellaMaris, use the third link (starting with "XPath API"), it links to the XPath API. But see [Michael Kay's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32726464/111575), he explains how you can configure it.

Comment: I use s9api like both of you mentioned. And I checked the [examples](https://code.google.com/p/vo-urp/source/browse/trunk/src/org/ivoa/xml/S9APIExamples.java?r=2) , but I cant figured out how to use the advantage e.g. regular expression. 'XPathSelector selector = xpath.compile("//property[matches(@value = '^title_q\\d+$')]").load();'

Comment: @stella, you are not applying the matches function correctly, first argument is the value to match, second argument is the regular expression.

Comment: thx, you are right. the "=" should be a ",". The xml-tag looks like '<property name="name" value="title_q4"/>' and I want to find all nodes where value is "title_q" followed by digits "\d+" and and with a digit "$" but it does not find my anything in my example.

Comment: @stella, I suggest you ask a different question, as that diverges from the current question. Remember that stackoverflow is about one question, one (or several) answers. See also [ask].

Answer (score 10):

In the latest release of Saxon, the JAR file no longer contains the meta-inf services file advertising it as a JAXP XPath factory provider. This is because too many applications were having problems: if the application is written and tested to work with the XPath 1.0 engine that comes with the JDK, there is a good chance it will fail if you try running it with Saxon's XPath 2.0 engine, and this was happening simply as a result of Saxon being on the class path. So if you want to use Saxon as your XPath engine, you now have to make the request explicit, e.g. by instantiating [`net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/xpath/package-summary.html#package_description) directly.

By that I mean calling `new XPathFactoryImpl()` instead of `XPathFactoryImpl.newInstance()` because it's inherited from `XPathFactory`.

However, because the XPath 2.0 type system is so much richer than XPath 1.0, the JAXP interface is really quite clumsy, and I would recommend [using the s9api interface](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/xpath-api/s9api-xpath.html) instead.

Answer (score 7):

I use Saxon-HE 9.8.0-5 like this:

```
Processor processor = new Processor(false);
XdmNode xdm = processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)));
XdmValue result = processor.newXPathCompiler().evaluate(query, xdm);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
    sb.append(result.itemAt(i).getStringValue());
    if (i + 1 != result.size()) {
        sb.append('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: So nice and short, I hope lots of people can find this and be enlightened by it! It took a long evolution from the first Java XML APIs to get to this simple straight-forwardness!

Comment: Since XdmValues are Iterable, you can write the last part using Streams:
`StreamSupport.stream(result.spliterator(), false)  
.map(XdmItem::getStringValue)  
.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));`

Answer (score 2):

Using the S9API is never as simple as it should be.  Here's the simplest working example that I could create.  It's a complete unit test that works with Saxon 9.7 HE in NetBeans 8.

Assuming this XML (simple.xml):

```
<person>
    <firstname>James</firstname>
    <age>25</age>
</person>
```

Run this unit test, which is looking for the firstname node:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException;
import net.sf.saxon.Configuration;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.NamespaceConstant;
import net.sf.saxon.om.DocumentInfo;
import net.sf.saxon.om.NodeInfo;
import net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException;
import net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class xPath2
{
    @Test
    public void mytest() throws XPathFactoryConfigurationException, XPathException, XPathExpressionException     
    {
        System.setProperty("javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:" + NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON, "net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl");
        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance(NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON);
        XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new File("simple.xml").toURI().toString());
        SAXSource saxSource = new SAXSource(inputSource);
        Configuration config = ((XPathFactoryImpl) xPathFactory).getConfiguration();
        DocumentInfo document = config.buildDocument(saxSource);      
        String xPathStatement = "//firstname";
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(xPathStatement);  
        List matches = (List) xPathExpression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET); 
        if (matches != null)
        {
            for (Iterator iter = matches.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
            {
                NodeInfo node = (NodeInfo) iter.next();
                assertEquals("firstname", node.getDisplayName());
                assertEquals("James", node.getStringValue()); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simplified version of one of the examples that come with the Saxon 9.7  resources (http://www.saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml).

Note that the xPath statement isn't xPath 2.0, but this code will work with a 2.0 statement.

Comment: This example isn't using s9api. (Did you mean it to?) See [a list of the classes involved in s9api for XPath](www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/xpath-api/s9api-xpath.html). The different XPath APIs in Saxon are: [s9api](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/package-summary.html#package_description) (preferred), [xpath](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/xpath/package-summary.html#package_description), and [sxpath](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/sxpath/package-summary.html#package_description).